# Cannot enable the internet connection when installing Linux on HP Compaq 6200 Pro SFF desktop

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

I am trying to install **Ubuntu 22.04** on a **HP Compaq 6200 Pro SFF**. I am new to Linux. I realized I cannot enable the internet connection during the install. I installed the OS without the internet but cannot update anything afterwards.
In the **Setup**, the **Storage/Boot Order** is disabled in the menu, by default.
The only option enabled there is **Storage Options**/**Sata Emulation** that is set to "**AHCI Mode**", the other choice (not selected by default) being "**IDE Mode**".
"**Security"/"Network boot**" is also disabled by default.
"**AMT Configuration**" is always enabled by default and if I disable it and save the setup on exit, it comes back on to "enabled" at the next boot. I have a strange feeling that this AMT is the culprit for not having an internet connection.
I have to say that I had Windows 7 on this PC before and installed Ubuntu without keeping any Windows partition, so wiping everything out.
Could you please point me in the right direction to enable the internet connection during the Linux install? **Many thanks** in advance for your help. **Much appreciated**.

Comment: Does Linux not recognize your network device? Ubuntu typically includes a place where you can connect, especially if you're using a wireless connection, or if you're using a wired connection and so long as the hardware supports it, it just works.

Comment: "Does Linux not recognize your network device?" I do not know how I can verify that. I am now dropped to the root environment and if I type "ip route" and hit Enter, it comes back with nothing. If I type "ip addr", it gives me the link/ether address and the local machine name (eno1)

Comment: 1. "99% of the 6200 Pro's only come with wired networking capabilities."https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktops-Archive-Read-Only/HP-Compaq-6200-Pro-Does-not-have-wireless-network/td-p/6103180" 2. For either WiFi or Ethernet, you might need to download the driver for the specific network adapter, possibly Intel 82579LM Gigabit Ethernet, or  Realtek RTL8191SU Wireless. Look for instructions online on incorporating the driver into the kernel.

Comment: Thanks for the info. As it happens, I've tried the wired connection that I could not get going. I will try and download some drivers that match the hardware.